# Jenkins HTML EMail report - Selenium NUnit

Tags: jenkins

My current setup is - Visual Studio 10 + Selenium + NUnit + Selenium Grid + Jenkins.
I have configured Jenkins to trigger an email after the build. But I want to include the HTML result report in the email body. Someone please guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the report is in your build's workspace, you can use the Editable Email Notification post build step  (provided by the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)) and include the token

```
${FILE,path="PATH"}
Includes the content of a specified file (path) relative to the workspace root.
```

Click the question mark next to Content Token Reference in the job configuration to see the full list of available tokens.

Comment: I get unexpected token: FILE @